# get html content of a page with Silverlight

Tags: c#, html, silverlight, runtime

I'm trying to get the html content of a page using silverlight. Webresponse and request classes don't work in silverlight.

I did some googling and I found something. This is what i tried:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
 {
  string result;
  WebClient client;

  public MainPage()
  {
   InitializeComponent();
   this.result = string.Empty;
   this.client = new WebClient();
   this.client.DownloadStringCompleted += ClientDownloadStringCompleted;
  }

  private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
   string url = "http://www.nu.nl/feeds/rss/algemeen.rss";

   this.client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));

   if (this.result != string.Empty && this.result != null)
   {
    this.txbSummery.Text = this.result;
   }
  }

  private void ClientDownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
   this.result = e.Result;
   //handle the response.
  }
 }
```

It gives me a runtime error after pressing the button:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details.   at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
   at System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
   at JWTG.MainPage.ClientDownloadStringCompleted(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadStringCompleted(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringOperationCompleted(Object arg)

I've tried numerous things but all failed.

What am i missing? Or does anyone know how i could achieve this in a different way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are getting a JScript error. Your posted code has nothing to do with the error. I just tried your snippet, and it works. BTW: you have to move that `this.txbSummery.Text = this.result;` into your `ClientDownloadStringCompleted` method. Currently, you are trying to put the text into the textbox before it is downloaded. That obviously doesnt work.

Comment: Have a look at: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/54721.aspx perhaps that helps you. The issue may be a misconfigured `web.config` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to clientaccesspolicy.xml. Read more here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(VS.95).aspx

> "If the connection request was from a WebClient or an HTTP class to a cross-domain site, the Silverlight runtime tries to download the security policy file using the HTTP protocol. The Silverlight runtime first tries to download a Silverlight policy file with a name of "clientaccesspolicy.xml" at the root of the requested target domain using the HTTP protocol.
>
> If the "clientaccesspolicy.xml" is either not found (the web request returns a 404 status code), returned with an unexpected mime-type, is not valid XML, or has an invalid root node, then the Silverlight runtime will issue a request for a for the Flash policy file with a name of "crossdomain.xml" at the root of the requested target domain, using the HTTP protocol.
>
> HTTP redirects for the policy file are not allowed. A redirect for a policy file will result in a SecurityException of access denied."

Comment: Hi,

I figured it out. The website i was trying to access with silverlight doesn't have the policy file. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, instead of your `btn1_Click` and `ClientDownloadStringCompleted` methods. It invokes the GUI thread after the feed is downloaded to update the textbox. If it fails because of an error on the network, it will unpack the exception (contained as an inner exception in a `TargetInvocationException`) and rethrow the inner exception.

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string url = "http://www.nu.nl/feeds/rss/algemeen.rss";

    this.client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
}

private void ClientDownloadStringCompleted(object sender, 
                      DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => this.txbSummery.Text = e.Result ?? "");
    }
    catch (TargetInvocationException tiex)
    {
        throw tiex.InnerException;
    }
}
```

If the error occures again (I guess that will happen), please post a stacktrace and error message here.

Comment: Hi,

Somehow i overlooked this post :o

This is what i get:

throw new Error("Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details.   at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()\n   at System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()\n   at JWTG.MainPage.<>c__DisplayClass2.<ClientDownloadStringCompleted>b__0()");

there is no stacktrace

Comment: Damn that is again boxed in an exception. So could you perhaps take a look at the innerException then? Either use the debugger, or just replace `throw tiex.InnerException;` with `throw tiex.InnerException.InnerException;`

Comment: It never gets that far, it stops at Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => this.txbSummery.Text = e.Result ?? ""); but see my post under this one for further info

Answer (score 1):

You try it

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "http://www.nu.nl/feeds/rss/algemeen.rss";

        this.client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));

    }

    private void ClientDownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Stream s = e.Result;
        StreamReader strReader = new StreamReader(s);
        string webContent = strReader.ReadToEnd();
        s.Close();
        this.txbSummery.Text =webContent;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
this.client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));
```

you are stating an asynchroneous download in a background thread. And in the next line you somehow expect that it is aready completed?

If you have no knowledge about Threading just try with DownloadString first. Then your code will work.

Comment: Hi,

I tried putting that 'next line' in the download callback, but that didn't fixed the runtime error.

Where can i find this 'downloadstring'? What class does it belong to?

Comment: @Foxfire: you dont really want to make a blocking call to retrieve a webpage, do you? Yustme should just use the `DownloadStringAsync`, but put the logic of handling the returned data into the `ClientDownloadStringCompleted` method.

Comment: @Yustme: You can't put the thing afterwards into the event either because it will be called from a different thread.

Comment: @Philip: Yes I would want that - at least until he gets the error sorted out. And he can't just put his current logic there because this.txbSummery runs on another thread as the event invocation.